# Recycler view not displaying data from Firebase Firestore using Firebase UI

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm trying to fetch data from a collection in Firestore and display it in a recycler view. I'm getting no error from my Logcat and my code too.

[Database snapshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w65u7.png)

RecyclerViewAdapter

public class AvailableMealsAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Meal_Model, AvailableMealsAdapter.MealsHolder> {

```
public AvailableMealsAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Meal_Model> options) {
    super(options);

}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MealsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Meal_Model model) {
        holder.availableMealNameTV.setText(model.getMeal_name());
        holder.availableMealPriceTV.setText(model.getPrice());


    Glide.with(holder.availableMealIV.getContext())
            .load(model.getMeal_imageSrc())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_no_food_24)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.availableMealIV);

       // holder.availableMealIV.setImageResource(model.getMeal_imageSrc());

}

@NonNull
@Override
public MealsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.available_item,
            parent, false);
    return new MealsHolder(view);
}

class MealsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public ImageView availableMealIV;
    public TextView availableMealNameTV, availableMealPriceTV;

    public MealsHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        availableMealIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IVOrderPicture);
        availableMealNameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVFoodItemOrder);
        availableMealPriceTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TVPriceOrder);
    }
}
```

}

Model Class

public class Meal_Model {

```
private String meal_name;
private String price;
private int meal_imageSrc;

public Meal_Model(String meal_name, String price, int meal_imageSrc) {
    this.meal_name = meal_name;
    this.price = price;
    this.meal_imageSrc = meal_imageSrc;
}

public String getMeal_name() {
    return meal_name;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public int getMeal_imageSrc() {
    return meal_imageSrc;
}
```

}

Main Fragment Class -> This is where the displaying is supposed to happen.

public class AvailableMealsFragment extends Fragment {

```
private Available_Meals_Adapter available_meals_adapter;
private AvailableMealsAdapter mealsAdapter;
RecyclerView mealRV;
private ArrayList<Meal_Model> mealModelArrayList;
View view;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private CollectionReference mealsReference;
private FirebaseFirestore db;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available_meals, container, false);

    progressDialog=  new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
    progressDialog.show();

    initRecyclerView(view);
    //listData();
    return view;
}

public void initRecyclerView(View view) {

    db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mealsReference= db.collection("meals");

    Query query= mealsReference.orderBy("Meal Name", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Meal_Model> options= new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Meal_Model>()
            .setQuery(query, Meal_Model.class).build();
    mealsAdapter= new AvailableMealsAdapter(options);

    if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    RecyclerView availableRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.RVMealItems);
    availableRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    availableRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    mealsAdapter.startListening();
    availableRecyclerView.setAdapter(mealsAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mealsAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mealsAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: I have included the database screenshot.